# Word break (leetcode #139) Python solution timeout -- is memoization not working?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm solving [leetcode #139](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/) and for some reason, I'm getting time limit exceeded. Am I using memoization improperly?

```py
class Solution:
    
    memo = set()
    
    def wordBreak(self, s: str, wordDict: List[str]) -> bool:
        self.memo = set(wordDict)
        
        return self.word_break(s)
    
    def word_break(self, s):
        if s in self.memo:
            return True

        for i in range(1, len(s)):
            head = s[:i]
            tail = s[i:]
            
            head_possible = self.word_break(head)
            tail_possible = self.word_break(tail)
            
            if head_possible:
                self.memo.add(head)
            if tail_possible:
                self.memo.add(tail)
            
            if head_possible and tail_possible:
                return True
        
        return False
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Your solution works fine without TLE, if we would just enable [lru_cache()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

```
class Solution:
    
    memo = set()
    
    def wordBreak(self, s: str, wordDict: List[str]) -> bool:
        self.memo = set(wordDict)
        
        return self.word_break(s)
    @lru_cache(None)
    def word_break(self, s):
        if s in self.memo:
            return True

        for i in range(1, len(s)):
            head = s[:i]
            tail = s[i:]
            
            head_possible = self.word_break(head)
            tail_possible = self.word_break(tail)
            
            if head_possible:
                self.memo.add(head)
            if tail_possible:
                self.memo.add(tail)
            
            if head_possible and tail_possible:
                return True
        
        return False
```

- This'd also pass without Time Limit Exceeded:

```
class Solution:
    def wordBreak(self, s, words):
        dp = [False] * len(s)
        for i in range(len(s)):
            for word in words:
                k = i - len(word)
                if word == s[k + 1:i + 1] and (dp[k] or k == -1):
                    dp[i] = True
        return dp[-1]
```

Comment: What am I missing without using lru cache?

Comment: But why does using lru cache make a difference? Shouldn't everything be inside the memoization dict? Why would lru_cache help?

Comment: No, that's what I was referring to -- the answers should be cached inside the memoization dictionary anyways, so wouldn't lru_cache not make a difference?